# How to order by relationship when the related table has an alias

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

We have a table called `Client` and client belongs to a user in two ways, a `client` can have an `updater` and has a `creator`. It also belongs to a `company`.

```
belongs_to :creator, class_name: 'User'
belongs_to :updater, class_name: 'User'
```

I am trying to grab all clients for the current parent object `company` they belong to and then order them alphabetically by the name of their `creator`

Here is what I currently have tried

```
current_company.clients.includes(:creator).order("creator.name #{sort_dir}")
```

If I put `:user` in the includes it throws an error that user is not on the table.

```
Association named 'user' was not found on Client;
```

This was the closest I was able to get with what I found online.

Comment: Does `current_company.clients.includes(:creator).order("users.name #{sort_dir}")` work?

Comment: Yes it appears that it does, if you make that the answer I will gladly accept it to give you credit because you just saved me a ton of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to see how the query looks like is to call `.to_sql`.

You will see that when the `join` is performed it uses the table name, `users`, instead of the relation name, `creator`.

This should work:

```
current_company.clients.includes(:creator).order("users.name #{sort_dir}")
```

Comment: thanks for that explanation I am sure I will come back to this to grab that at some point.  Thanks again

Comment: You are welcome !